# How to add the sidebar in all category page

Tags: categories, sidebar

I created custom post type. I created category called product-categories. I listed all categories in sidebar.php. How to show the sidebar in all the category pages listing all the categories. Sidebar.php code is,

'name',
        'order'              => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'         => 0,
        'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
        'child_of'           => 21,
        'hierarchical'       => 1,
        'number'             => null,
        'echo'               => 1,
        'taxonomy'           => 'product-categories',
        'walker'             => null,
       'title_li'           =>''
); ?>

I want to display this code visible in all the category pages. Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code will work as for per your  custom post type

add the following code in sidebar.php to show your custom post type category

```
<?php
 //list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories  (also useful as a widget)
  $orderby = 'name';
  $show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
   $pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
   $hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $taxonomy = 'genre';
  $title = '';

  $args = array(
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
     'title_li' => $title
     );
 ?>
  <ul>
 <?php
   wp_list_categories($args);
 ?>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(is_category()){
// code stuff
}
```

This function executes When any Category archive page is being displayed.

Comment: how to check the parent category, ie I want to check the condition for the page, taxonomy and for this parent category, I checked is_page(80)||(is_taxonomy('product-categories') how to check for parent category